# How can I parse XML in Netsuite and get a specific value in groovy

Tags: xml, soap, groovy, netsuite

the response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">   <soapenv:Header>
    <platformMsgs:documentInfo xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
      <platformMsgs:nsId>WEBSERVICES_TSTDRV1371590_041220151334115279325827527_fefe8c</platformMsgs:nsId>
    </platformMsgs:documentInfo>   </soapenv:Header>   <soapenv:Body>
    <addResponse xmlns="">
      <platformMsgs:writeResponse xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <platformCore:status xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" isSuccess="true"/>
        <platformMsgs:baseRef xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" internalId="5450" type="customer" xsi:type="platformCore:RecordRef"/>
      </platformMsgs:writeResponse>
    </addResponse>   
</soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

how can I get the internal Id of this xml using groovy my code is :

def slurper = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response.text);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean just:

```
def slurper = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response.text);
def id = slurper.Body.addResponse.writeResponse.baseRef.@internalId

assert id == '5450'
```

Comment: darnit, I returned the wrong Id...  couldn't find internalId amongst all the text there.  Xml is non-human-readable :)

Comment: String internalId = slurper['Body']['addResponse']['writeResponse']['baseRef'].@internalId

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer:

```
def slurper = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response.text)
def internalId = slurpXml['Body']['addResponse']['writeResponse']['baseRef'].attribute('internalId')
```

This completely ignores the namespacing, of course.  You don't need to worry about it in your example, though.

Comment: I got tis error: 
Caught: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'WEBSERVICES_TSTDRV1371590_041220151323416430516371494_eca19dUNIQUE_CUST_ID_REQDA customer record with this ID already exists. You must enter a unique customer ID for each record you create. To correct this record, click <a href='javascript:history.go(-1);';>back</a> and enter a new customer ID in the Customer field. Then, click Submit.' with class 'groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild' to class 'groovy.util.XmlSlurper'

Comment: how do I declare slurpXml because it Cannot cast object slurpXml

Comment: Try now, with `def` for the first variable. The parse text method doesn't return an xmlslurper

Comment: I already did that, What I want is to get the internalId of the xml response but I cannot get the value of that since it its under the status value. internalId has an "=" sign I don't know how to get the Value